# icu-dev library removes /bin/sh or messes up the image entry point

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to build an optimized PHP image. The strategy that I chose, was to install and compile everything in a build stage and then copy the extensions to a new stage and enable them. This allows me to shed 200MB.

All is good until the intl extension. This extension needs the icu-dev library, but once I install that, /bin/sh disappears, or somehow the entry point gets all messed up. This is very low level stuff and I don't really know how to even search for the issue.

```
# Prepare compiled extensions
FROM php:8.1-cli-alpine as build

RUN apk --no-cache add autoconf build-base icu-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install intl

FROM php:8.1-cli-alpine

COPY --from=build /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/intl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/intl.so

RUN apk --no-cache add icu-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-enable intl
```

This is the output of the image build

```
[+] Building 1.6s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 429B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.1-cli-alpine                                                                                                                                                                                                1.3s
 => [auth] library/php:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [build 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/php:8.1-cli-alpine@sha256:858d56e3ee12e138a9119380fb361a5b01f1ff9369d372ef73042b6cd4753f25                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/3] RUN apk --no-cache add autoconf build-base icu-dev                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/3] RUN docker-php-ext-install intl                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/4] COPY --from=build /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/intl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/intl.so                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 3/4] RUN apk --no-cache add icu-dev                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 4/4] RUN docker-php-ext-enable intl                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.3s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 > [stage-1 4/4] RUN docker-php-ext-enable intl:
#10 0.251 container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-enable intl]: exit code: 1
make: *** [Makefile:4: build] Error 1
```

Here's a reproduction repo, in case anyone is interested

https://github.com/benelori/icu-dev-reproduction

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately I did not provide all the details:

1. The command I ran for building the image was `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . -t test/icu:latest`
2. Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57

It seems like this is not reproducible for everyone, so I do not know what else to provide.

In the end though, if I don't enable build kit, then the build command runs successfully, therefore I marked the answer below as accepted.

Comment: Please edit the question to include any necessary details in the question itself.  If the link to the full repository is useful feel free to leave it, but code details like the image's Dockerfile need to be included in the question, not just via a link to an external repository.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here with your multistage build but this clearly messes up your extension. You don't really need a multistage here as alpine `apk` provides tools to deal with build dependencies.

I did not fully dig in the process so that might be further optimized, but here is a Dockerfile which:

- Installs required build packages as a virtual package
- Installs `icu-dev` and the php `intl` extension. Note that the extension is installed enabled so there is no need to do that in a separate step
- Removes the build dependencies virtual package once this is done

All of this takes place in a single layer so you end up with only what is strictly needed (i.e. the `intl` extension and required `icu-dev` package, unless I forgot some additional possible cleanup...)

```
FROM php:8.1-cli-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache autoconf build-base --virtual build_deps && \
    apk add --no-cache icu-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl && \
    apk del build_deps
```

You can build from that Dockerfile file as

```
docker build -t test:test .
```

and see the extension is available as expected:

```
$ docker run -it --rm test:test sh -c "php -i | grep -A 7 intl"
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-intl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini

PHP API => 20210902
PHP Extension => 20210902
Zend Extension => 420210902
Zend Extension Build => API420210902,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20210902,NTS
--
intl

Internationalization support => enabled
ICU version => 69.1
ICU Data version => 69.1
ICU Unicode version => 13.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
intl.default_locale => no value => no value
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
intl.use_exceptions => Off => Off

json

json support => enabled

libxml
```

The resulting image is 135MB (compared to 366MB without removing the build dependencies). This makes it roughly 40MB more than the base image which is 94.2MB at time of this writing.

Comment: autoconf, build-base and docker-php-ext-enable will bring some packages in that are needed for the compilation and it's almost 200MB.

I'm aware of the 1 stage build method and it works, yes, but my question is very specific to this multi stage build and I would like help to debug that specific issue.

Comment: The above is perfectly addressing your requirement and is building an image which does not contain those build dependencies in the end as I explained in my answer. If you want help do debug a specific issue, you have to provide more debugging info because as it is, it is absolutely not clear what the error is and where it could come from.

Comment: I don't know what else to provide. If you run the build with that Dockerfile, you should get the error that I posted. This SO post is a request to help with that specific issue.

Comment: Note that your above Dockerfile runs without error on my side and produces an image which is 141MB so slightly over the one I proposed above, unless you group those last RUN commands into a single in which case the sizes are exactly equivalent.

Comment: *sigh I did not provide all the details. The way I was running the command was with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 . Running the command to normal way successfully built my image as well.

I will mark your answer as the correct one, but I will also edit my post and point towards this exchange with what the solution to the issue was. Is that ok?

Comment: I built all of the above (question and answer) with buildkit enabled. https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/4a0248f2261c6289bb2d3b2581f5b69c

Comment: That's very weird. I tried with the --no-cache flag as you did and building with buildkit still throws the error.
Thanks a lot for your help btw, I don't think I would have thought about running this without buildkit to be honest :D